# Paypal Express Checkout in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, codeigniter-url

I want my clients to pay using Paypal's express checkout flow. My website is developed in CodeIgniter. I am receiving 404 error when the customer cancel and return to the website bcoz Paypal adds ?token=$$$$$$$ at the end of the cancel url.

Can you help me friends?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you'll need to be able to make the URL with the GET parameter work and access the token supplied.

First in system/application/config.php, change:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

... to ...

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "PATH_INFO";
```

That will allow the URL to route in the usual way.  Once that's in place, add this like to the top of your controller method:

```
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$_GET);
```

That will reinstate the $_GET array, after which you can use this to access the token value if required:

```
$token = $this->input->get('token');
```

... and you're all done!

Answer (score -2):

take it out of CI. You always have the $_SESSION to communicate.